# shield ui grid get selected row data

Tags: grid, selectedindex, shieldui

I m trying get selected row data as JSON object from shield ui grid.I tried with [this](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/methods/select) and [this](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/methods/selectedRowIndices) examples given in their documentation.But non of them work as needed. `grid.select()` gives me **`TypeError: c.value is not a function`** 
and `grid.selectedRowIndices()` gives **TypeError: `grid.selectedRowIndices is not a function`**.

```
events: {
                selectionChanged: function (e) {
                    //var data = e.target.dataSource.view;

                    var grid = $("#user_grid").swidget();
                    //console.log(grid.selectedRowIndices());
                      console.log(grid.select());
```

Any help would be appreciable.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the selected items in the grid, you can use the selectedRowIndeces, as described here:
http://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/methods/selectedRowIndices
Make sure that you are using the latest version of the widget.